# How to transfer RealmResults accross threads

Tags: android, realm

I'm using a recycler view in my app and would like to do some computation on a background thread, obtain a list of RealmObjects, and refresh my adapter to it.

As a bit of background, I have a non trivial sorting requirement, and the recycler view needs to display objects that result from queries on different tables(though they still produce the same object type). I don't want to do these potentially expensive queries on the main thread.

What is the best way to do this? AFAIK, I can

1. Get a list of ids(String) from the background thread, and do a query on the main thread. So I would do something like `realm.where(ObjectA.class).in(listOfIds).findAll()`. However, I don't think I have a guarantee that the order of the collection is the order of my listOfIds, which i have sorted in the background. I could then sort the realm collection manually.
2. Or, I can do a `realm.copyFromRealm(listOfObjectA)`, assuming I have gotten a list of objects from my background thread. With this way it feels cleaner to me but i obviously lose the auto-refreshing functionality, not to mention that it will be memory-intensive. It seems that the expensive copying would take place on the main thread, which would undermine my efforts to move things into the background thread.

I was hoping there was a method that would allow me to transfer RealmResults or RealmList from one thread to the other. Does anyone have recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: How many items are you juggling? And what is this "complicated sort"? Are you sure you cannot use `findAllSortedAsync()`?

Comment: `realm.where(Photo.class).equalTo("folder.id", folderId).findAll()`?

Comment: My entire comment got truncated - apologies.
1. Photos are contained in Folder, each Photo can be in multiple Folders.
2. Each Photo has a unique sort order in each Folder
3. All Folders have a unique sort order
4. RecyclerView displays all Photos from all Folders sequentially, in a continuous stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### findAllSortedAsync

> I have a non trivial sorting requirement

If this sorting is based purely on your RealmObject fields, you can use `RealmQuery.findAllSortedAsync(...)` method, which will execute the query **and** sorting for you on a separate worker thread. This is the best option. If it's possible, you can also do sorting in two stages, one using `findAllSortedAsync` and second one on main thread on already obtained objects - possibly the second stage would not be as costly if the results are pre-sorted by realm.

> and the recycler view needs to display objects that result from queries on different tables

You can look for a possibility to create a linking between these objects, for example if RealmObject **A** has a field **b**, you can sort **A** by fields of **b** also - this could fix your problem, and keep everything in one realm query.

### Requery with sorted IDs (NO)

> Get a list of ids(String) from the background thread, and do a query on the main thread...

You're right - there is no guarantee of the results being returned in the original ID list order, so this is not really an option.

### copyFromRealm

> Or, I can do a realm.copyFromRealm(listOfObjectA)...

That is correct, however you have to be aware of the limitiations and memory overhead using this method, namely:

- you get a snapshot of the data and have to manually update the recycler with new snapshots
- single change to an object conforming to your original query will trigger an update and, possibly, sorting all over again

> It seems that the expensive copying would take place on the main thread, which would undermine my efforts to move things into the background thread.

Not really, if you perform `copyFromRealm` on thread **A** and pass the list to thread **B**, the hard copying of the values from realm will be executed by thread **A**, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not move "live" RealmObjects across threads, so the two options you've laid out are pretty much what you're left with.

If you do your query on the background thread and use `copyFromRealm` to create disconnected objects, sort them, and then pass those back to the main thread, that will all happen on the background thread, so you're fine there.

(Small note: if you display the data in a different format than it is in Realm, you could also map it to a class that's quicker to then populate your views from instead of using the Realm object in the UI, since you lost the sync features anyway.)

Otherwise, if you need them to be connected to Realm, I think you will have to do the ID list transfer and suffer the cost of sorting them on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use copyFromRealm method
In java:

```
MyRealmObject unManagedRealmObject= realmInstance.copyFromRealm(myRealmObject);
```

Well in kotlin, we can do it in a more better way:

```
var nonRealmObject: MyRealmObject?=null
            set(value) {    // here value is child of RealmObject
                    if (value!=null)
                         field = realmInstance.copyFromRealm(value)   // converting RealmObject to unmanaged realm object
                    else
                         field=null
            }
```

Now when you assign:

```
nonRealmObject = someRealmObject // set(value) method will be called and it will convert realm to unmanaged realm object
```

Note: `realmInstance` is an instance of Realm already created, if you create new reference make sure to close it when your work is done.

Comment: Your realm instance stays opened if you do it that way.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change there, now I have updated the answer.